# Stuck in N-Queens java algorithm. (Backtracking)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

Can someone give me a hint or guidance on my java program? I am stuck on the backtracking idea. Here is the code. If you take a look at the method solve(), it recursively calls itself, however I am stuck at a point where it fails to place more queens and tries to backtrack.

```
public NQueens(int N)
{
    this.N = N;
    board = new boolean[N][N];
    solved = solve(N);
    if(solved == true)
    {
        System.out.println(N+"x"+N+" solution:");
        printBoard(N);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("There is no solution for "+N+"x"+N+" board");
    }
}

public boolean solve(int waitingQueens)
{
    if(waitingQueens == 0) return true;

    for(int row = 0; row < N; row++)
    {

        for(int column = 0 ; column < N ; column++)
        {
            if(isValid(row, column))
            {
                board[row][column] = true;
                waitingQueens--;
                boolean solved = solve(waitingQueens);

                if(!solved)
                {
                    board[row][column] = false;

                    solved = solve(waitingQueens);
                }
                return solved;
            }

        }

    }

    return false;
}

public boolean isValid(int rowParam, int columnParam)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < N; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < N; y++)
        {
            if(board[x][y] == true) //find the already placed queens on the board and check if the queen about to be placed is on a valid position
            {
                if(x == rowParam) //check the validity of the row
                    return false;
                if(y == columnParam) //check the validity of the column
                    return false;
                if(Math.abs(x-rowParam) == Math.abs(y-columnParam)) //check the validity of the diagonals
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void printBoard(int printParam)
{
    for(int x1 = 0; x1 < printParam; x1++)
    {
        for(int y1 = 0; y1 < printParam; y1++)
        {
            if(board[x1][y1] == true)
            {
                System.out.print("Q ");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I remember those days. My best advice is to just work it our for yourself. Getting SO advice for your homework or your own personal challenges robs you of a very rewarding experience when you figure it out for yourself.

Comment: @robbmj Thanks for the advice. I got it working! I was almost jumping around in my room. :D

Comment: good to hear. My first exposure to recursion and backtracking was this same problem. I found it in the `arrays` chapter questions section of my Java text book. I spent almost a full day on it. But when I finally worked out the solution I really understood recursion. I guess the only way to understand recursion is to understand recursion ...

Comment: @ImAlwaysWrong Glad you got it working.  This concept is *not* an easy thing to grasp.

Answer (score 3):

I gather that this is the algorithm you're trying to implement:  Assume you already have `M` queens on the board (it looks like `M` = `N - waitingQueens` or something).  Then, you look for every empty square where you could place a queen.  If it's valid to place a queen there, you set the square in `board` to `true` and then call `solve` recursively to see if you can place `waitingQueens-1` more queens.

Your biggest problem lies in what happens if the recursive `solve` returns `false`.  Say it's a 4x4 board and `waitingQueens` is 4.  You'll place the first queen, then call `solve` with `waitingQueens=3`.  But suppose it says there's no solution.  You then do this:

```
            if(!solved)
            {
                board[row][column] = false;
                solved = solve(waitingQueens);
            }
```

This will set the square to `false`, which means the board is now empty again.  But then you call `solve(waitingQueens)` with `waitingQueens=3`, which means your recursive `solve` will now look for a solution that has only 3 queens on the board.  This can't be right.  And re-incrementing `waitingQueens` back to 4 is going to lead to infinite recursion, since `solve(4)` will be calling `solve(4)` with the same empty board.

The thing here is, you're already in a double loop that will look for every square where you could put a queen.  If you try to put a queen somewhere and it doesn't work out (the recursive call fails), you remove the queen, but then you let the double loop find the next valid square for you.  You do *not* want to do another recursive call.  So the above `solve(waitingQueens)` call should be removed.

Also, this needs to be fixed:

```
            waitingQueens--;
            boolean solved = solve(waitingQueens);
```

Decreasing `waitingQueens` is a bad idea, because if `solve` returns `false`, and you have to go back to the next loop iteration, `waitingQueens` will be one less than it was before, which is no good.  You could restore it by saying `waitingQueens++` in the `if (!solved)` branch, but why bother?  Leave `waitingQueens` alone, and replace the above two lines with

```
            boolean solved = solve(waitingQueens-1);
```

I'm not sure if those two fixes will be enough to produce a correct answer, but they're a start.  A couple other things I want to mention, although these are just optimizations: (1) Your loop in `solve` shouldn't even look at squares that aren't empty.  The way you wrote it, `isValid` will return `false` if you give it a square that isn't empty, but it does so in a roundabout way.  I'd probably check that the square is empty even before calling `isValid`.  (2) Once you've placed `M` queens in rows 0 to `M-1`, your recursive call shouldn't even look at those rows, since we know you can't have two queens in the same row.  And if you look through row `M` and don't find a solution, you can give up immediately, since we know that a correct solution must have a queen in every row.  So you really only need a single loop in `solve`.